# How to sent JavaScript Objects from the Client-Side and how to receive and parse them in Spring Boot Back-end?

Tags: javascript, java, json, spring-boot, axios

I have came and left this problem numerous times while trying to make my web apps and have gotten fed up with no results, to the point that I have to ask here, so please excuse me if I come off as venting... I am quite aggravated.

I am trying to send data in the form of key-value pairs from my client(vanilla js) to my back end(spring boot java). I have tried numerous ways of doing it but can't seem to find the correct way/combination to achieve what I want done. My current non-working code is as follows.

**Client-Side JS**

```
var object = {
        'id' : 1,
        'username' : 'jumpthruhoops',
        'password' : 'melodysteez'
    };

    Axios
        .post('http://localhost:8080/gameSchedule', JSON.stringify(object))
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response.data);
        });
```

**Back-End Spring Boot/Java**

```
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping(value = "/gameSchedule", headers = "Accept=application/json", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
public String getSchedule(@RequestBody String user) {
    System.out.println(user);
    return "test";
}
```

The following code is what I currently have that has given me any type of results close to what I'm looking for. It gives me the following printed line...

> %7B%22id%22%3A1%2C%22username%22%3A%22tdellard1%22%2C%22password%22%3A%22sisters3%22%7D=

...which I believe is a hex code for the string object I passed into the parameter. I'm not sure if this is from Spring Boot, or if this is what JSON.stringify does.  Since the User Object is a test object and actual object that I plan on passing in, is way more complex, I don't want to figure out how to decode the hex code, unless I can't get anything else going and I completely have to.

Because it is more complicated, I don't want to use a lot of @RequestParams("name") String VaribleName like 40 times in the parameter of the method. This was also the only other way to get results but passing those variables into a url is maddening.

Some other things I have tried are @ModelAttribute and (@RequestBody User user), both return errors, one that seems to be reoccurring is

> 018-10-30 23:38:29.346  WARN 12688 --- [io-8080-exec-10] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported]

So what I am pretty much asking is for guidance on what is the best way to send my data from Axios(form.serialize, JSON.stringify, JavaScript Object, etc.) and what corresponding method I need to use to obtain that data on my Spring Boot Back-End and make it manipulative so I can turn it into a POJO.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sending an object you have to use object  when receiving at back-end side and make sure that name of the field in request object and the field name of the class at back-end side must be same,
so it should be like this:

I am just making some changing in your code to access field:

```
var data = {  
        'id' : 1,
        'username' : 'jumpthruhoops',
        'password' : 'melodysteez'
    };
// name of variable(data variable) doesn't matter but inside everything consider as a body

axios.post('http://localhost:8080/gameSchedule', JSON.stringify(object), {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }
    }
    );
```

back-end side retrieve fields

```
//create one Student class to map fields with body 

@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping(value = "/gameSchedule", headers = "Accept=application/json", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
public String getSchedule(@RequestBody Student student) {
    System.out.println(student.id);
    System.out.println(student.username);
    System.out.println(student.password);
    return "test"
}
```

Comment: I still receive this error  
Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported]

Comment: You have to content type as an 'application/json' in header part while sending request,

as i have update in answer

Answer (score 0):

Just remove JSON.stringify(object) and put object.

```
Axios
    .post('http://localhost:8080/gameSchedule', object)
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
    });
```

You can see an example on POST request here [axios documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios)

On Spring boot you have to create an entity like this:

```
@Entity
public class UserAccount implements Serializable {

@Id
private Long id;

@Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
@Size(max = 255)
private String userName;

@Column(nullable = false)
@NotNull
private String password;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
```

}

and change your code for here

```
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping(value = "/gameSchedule", headers = "Accept=application/json", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
public UserAccount getSchedule(@RequestBody UserAccount user) {
    System.out.println(user.getUserName());
    return user;
}
```

Comment: But how to I retrieve and manipulate the object from Spring Boot?

Comment: Just create an class UserAcount like this entity https://github.com/svlada/springboot-security-jwt/blob/master/src/main/java/com/svlada/entity/User.java, you can see on this answer I updated it :)